# How to configure Ionic 3 Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been searching around on google and the Ionic docs site and am confused on something. I see there is two seperate plugins. Firebase and FirebaseAnalytics. It seems like Ionic 3 doesn't really support the FirebaseAnalytics plugin since it's not on Ionic 3 docs site and when I tried to install it I got all kinds of dependency errors and when I tried to fix them it casued even more issues. Can someone who knows about this explain to my what I would be missing if I just used the Ionic 3 Firebase plugin and not newer exact FireBaseAnalytics plugin?

Comment: please mark answer if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are looking at the v3 documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase-analytics/).

As mentioned in the docs, you need to install these two things to your project:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase-analytics@4
```

Notice how the ionic-native firebase analytics module is specifically version 4. This is what makes it compatible with v3. Go through the instructions in those v3 documents and you should be good.